# Angular-CLI/Angular2: Non-standard chars only load correctly in index.html, not in components via ng serve

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

In my Angular2 App: when I use "ng serve" or "ng build" extended characters are not rendered correctly in the Components. Extended chars directly in index.html work fine.

I suspect it is something to do with the way the files are being saved and served but I am new to ng2, webpack and CLI so not really sure how to test that theory just yet.

The charset in index.html is set to "charset=UTF-8" and if I view the individual component HTML page BEFORE bundling in the browser it renders correctly.

**Repro Steps:**

- Copy and paste "Próximamente" into the Index.html output area, as well as into a component's template.
- Run "ng-serve".
- The one in index.html will render correctly but the one in the template will not
- Note: The same happens with the deployed Prod ng build ouput

**Versions**

- Chrome: 53.0.2785.143 m
- Angular: 2.1.0
- Windows: 10
- Webpack: 2.1.0 Beta 25
- Angular-CLI: 1.0.0 Beta 18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the content of `.ts` files (templates) is also encoded in *UTF-8*. In other words - the `index.html`'s `charset` should match the real physical encoding of served files.

PS: You can easily check actual encoding in text editors *MS VSC*, *Notepad++*, `file -i *`,  etc.

Comment: Hmm yes, you are right. I did not think to check this as when I viewed the individual component file html in the browser it rendered correctly... so I assume it was a packaging issue. So then the next question is:  Is it the Angular-cli that is generating these HTML components that needs to change (everytime I generate a new component I will have to re-save it with the right encoding). Thanks

Comment: I run `ng generate` commands inside _MS VSC_ and the files are in _UTF-8_ even on _Windows_. You can check the source code of the `ng generate` if it is or isn't platform dependent.